# How to make create two y-axis labels with a grid of facets with a single x-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, cowplot

I have been struggling with `ggplot` to display these plots how I would like. My data have 2 factors, `quarter` and `species`. Station will be on the x-axis, value on the y-axis, and the constituent will be used with the `facet_wrap`. I want `quarter` differentiated with shapes, and `species` with colors.

The issue is I'm trying to replicate a figure done in SigmaPlot. It is 4x4 grid of plots, with the first two rows of the first column are empty, to allow for the placement of the legend. My original plan was to have two separate facets made using `facet-wrap`, and combine those, however, this doesn't maintain the 4x4 arrangement, it transforms it into a 1x2, which ruins alignment of plots and shrinks the larger faceted grid.

My next thought was to create each plot individually, then arrange them in a grid using cowplot. This presents the plots how I'd like them arranged, but I can't figure out how to have two y-axis labels, due to different units. One label would be centered on the two leftmost plots, and one centered on the left of the next column of 4 plots.

I'm trying to use this code (just copy the example data below, and run):

```
library(ggplot)
library(gridExtra)

test.data1 <- test.data[1:95, ]
test.data2 <- test.data[96:111, ]

testplot1 <- ggplot(test.data1, aes(Station, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(quarter), fill = Species)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22)) +
  labs(x = "Station", y = "Unit a", shape = "Sampling Quarter", fill = "Species") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), shape = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ constituent, ncol = 3, scales = "free_y")

testplot2 <- ggplot(test.data2, aes(Station, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(quarter), fill = Species))
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22)) +
  labs(x = "Station", y = "Unit b", shape = "Sampling Quarter", fill = "Species") +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), shape = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ constituent, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")

grid.arrange(testplot2, testplot1, ncol = 2)
```

Which generates this:

[image]

But I want it to be arranged like this, where the XX and YY plots from above are normalized in size with the other plots (this was done using individual plots, and using `plot_grid`):
[image]

Example data from a larger set:

```
test.data <- structure(list(Station = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("StA", "StB"), class = "factor"), 
CollectionDate = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("10/1/2017", 
"10/16/2017", "4/1/2017"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("SpA", "SpB", "SpC"), class = "factor"), 
quarter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2017 Q2", 
"2017 Q4"), class = "factor"), constituent = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
"J", "K", "L", "XX", "YY"), class = "factor"), value = c(16, 
35, 46, 23, 40, 19, 9, 50, 0.2, 1, 0.5698, 0.322, 1, 0.45, 
0.322, 0.5, 16, 9, 6, 19, 14, 13, 16, 9, 0, 0.004, 0, 0.004, 
1, 0.32, 1, 0.678, 0, 0.39, 0.23, 0, 0, 1.1, 0.5, 0.5, 9, 
4.9, 7, 4.768, 9, 8.65, 4.768, 6.54, 195, 195, 46, 46, 124, 
124, 218, 218, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.22, 0.4, 
0.22, 0.4, 0.22, 0.1, 0.99, 0.99, 1.2, 0.45, 0.765, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1.2, 4.3, 0.98, 0.99, 1.2, 1.2, 34, 34, 
65, 98, 150, 34, 65, 65, 2, 0, 4, 1.3, 5, 3.3, 1.56, 1, 9, 
0.36, 4, 4, 11, 2, 2.22, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-111L))
```

Comment: Instead of giving this super long data sample, I would recommend to create vectors with sampled characters/ integers, etc. This way of showing the data is rather off-putting and does not help to give a oversight over your actual question

Comment: Or move the data to the end of the post

Comment: Ok, I'll create vectors, and move it to the end for now.

Comment: One hack seems to increase the *keyheight* in `guide_legend`. See what I mean with `keyheight = 12`.

Comment: That's helping a bit, but `keywidth` doesn't seem to affect it, unfortunately. Just moves the legend text on top of the other plots.